# Not Receiving Temperature Data from Bluetooth Thermometer in Android App

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, android-bluetooth, bluetooth-gatt

I'm working on an Android app that interacts with a Bluetooth Low Energy (BLE) thermometer device. My goal is to read temperature data from the thermometer and display it in my app. However, despite correctly setting up the BLE communication, I'm facing issues receiving the expected temperature data.

This is my testing perpose project

This is my MainActivity

```
package com.example.bluetoothdevice

import android.Manifest
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGatt
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCallback
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattCharacteristic
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothGattDescriptor
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import java.util.UUID


class MainActivity: AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var bluetoothDevice : BluetoothDevice
    lateinit var gatt: BluetoothGatt

    var gattCallback: BluetoothGattCallback = object : BluetoothGattCallback() {

        override fun onConnectionStateChange(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int, newState: Int) {
            super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState)

            if(newState == BluetoothGatt.STATE_CONNECTED){
                Log.i("callback","Device connected")

                gatt.discoverServices()
            }
        }

        override fun onDescriptorWrite(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt?,
            descriptor: BluetoothGattDescriptor?,
            status: Int
        ) {
            super.onDescriptorWrite(gatt, descriptor, status)
            if(status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS){
                Log.i("callback","write descriptor done ")
                gatt?.readCharacteristic(descriptor?.characteristic)

            }

        }



        override fun onCharacteristicChanged(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
            value: ByteArray
        ) {

            Log.i("callback","indication value "+value.toString())
        }

        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU)
        override fun onServicesDiscovered(gatt: BluetoothGatt, status: Int) {

            super.onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status)

            Log.i("callback","services discovered "+gatt.services.size)

            val bluetoothGattService = gatt?.getService(UUID.fromString("00001809-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))

            if(bluetoothGattService != null){

                Log.i("callback","temperature service found "+bluetoothGattService.toString())

                var mReadCharacteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic =
                    bluetoothGattService.getCharacteristic(
                        UUID.fromString("00002a1c-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb")
                    )



                if (mReadCharacteristic != null) {
                    Log.i(
                        "Callback",
                        "temperature characteristic found "
                    )


                    gatt?.setCharacteristicNotification(mReadCharacteristic, true)

                    val descriptor = mReadCharacteristic.getDescriptor(UUID.fromString("00002902-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))

                    descriptor.value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE

                    gatt?.writeDescriptor(descriptor)
                    

                }
            }
        }

        override fun onCharacteristicRead(
            gatt: BluetoothGatt,
            characteristic: BluetoothGattCharacteristic,
            status: Int
        ) {
            super.onCharacteristicRead(gatt, characteristic, status)

            Log.i("callback","On characteristic Read "+ characteristic.value.decodeToString())

            val receivedData = characteristic.value // Your received data byte array

            val temperature = ((receivedData[1].toInt() and 0xFF) shl 8) or (receivedData[0].toInt() and 0xFF)

            val celsiusTemperature = temperature / 10.0

            Log.i("callback",celsiusTemperature.toString())

        }
    }


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        var bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()

        checkPermissions()

        for (device in bluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices) {

            if (device.name[0] == 'F') {
                 bluetoothDevice = bluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(device.address)

                toast(device.name.toString())

                gatt = device.connectGatt(this, false, gattCallback)

            }
        }

    }


    private fun checkPermissions() {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf<String>(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION),
                100
            )
            return
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT),
                100
            )
            return
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN),
                100
            )
            return
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        gatt.close()
        gatt.disconnect()
    }

}
```

This is Manifest file

```
Im trying to fetch temperature data from FORA IR42. The temperature data is Indicatable data. I can get other data like manufacturer name, serial number ext. But I couldn't get temperature data as Indicatable. The onCharacteristicChanged function is not triggering after data change. Please give me a solution for read the temperature data from the bluetooth thermometer. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth_le" android:required="true"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BluetoothDevice"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Im trying to fetch temperature data from FORA IR42. The temperature data is Indicatable data. I can get other data like manufacturer name, serial number ext. But I couldn't get temperature data as Indicatable. The onCharacteristicChanged function is not triggering after data change. Please give me a solution for read the temperature data from the bluetooth thermometer.

Comment: Have you tested the indications using a generic BLE exploration tool such as [nRF Connect](https://www.nordicsemi.com/Products/Development-tools/nrf-connect-for-mobile)? What happens when you just read the value without indication?

Answer (score 0):

1. When you enable Indicaton/Notification the onCharacteristicChanged callback is triggered not the onCharacteristicRead.
2. You should not do all the gatt operations in one shot, do it sequentially.
   i.e read serial number , once onCharacteristicRead is triggered do the next operation
3. Get a BLE android tool like nRF Connect, make sure your characteristic type is of Indication, if it is of type Notification try with

   `val cccDescriptor = characteristic?.getDescriptor(CCC_DESCRIPTOR_UUID)`

   `val value = BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE`

   `gatt?.writeDescriptor(cccDescriptor, value)`